# My JavaScript won't load in my WordPress HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am trying to run some simple JavaScript on one page of my WordPress site as a test, but it won't load.

An example of the code working correctly can be found at http://fiddle.jshell.net/psflannery/XAxWv/.

```
<div class="acord">
    <h3>Summer</h3>
    <div class="acorda">
        <h3>test1</h3>
        <div>test1cont</div>
        <h3>test2</h3>
        <div>test2cont</div>
        <div>
            <p>Editorial Intro</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h3>Spring</h3>
    <div class="acorda">
        <h3>test3</h3>
        <div>test3cont</div>
        <h3>test4</h3>
        <div>test4cont</div>
        <h3>test5</h3>
        <div>test5cont</div>
        <div>
            <p>Editorial Intro</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".acord").accordion({
        header: "> h3",
        heightStyle: "content",
        collapsible: true,
    });
    jQuery(".acorda").accordion({
        header: "h3",
        heightStyle: "content",
        active: false,
        collapsible: true,
    });
});
</script>
```

Can anyone provide some advice as to why the JavaScript is not loading?

As an extra note, I did successfully run the code with the Javascript loading, so really at a loss as to what the problem is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Alert</h2>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

I have modified the JavaScript thanks to suggestions made below. My only issue now is that I get an error on my page saying `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).accordion is not a function`.

I have tried adding the jQuery UI dependency in both the page file and the header.php file of my WordPress theme, but neither is working.

`<script src="code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Does someone know how to resolve the dependency issue?

Comment: If the JS is interacting with DOM elements, it needs to come after the HTML.

Comment: What debugging have you done? What errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: @Kevin I updated the code but am still having the same issue.

Comment: @j08691 I have no errors when running the code. I am honestly not sure how to debug the Javascript not loading.

Comment: You probably aren't loading jQuery on your wordpress site

Comment: @SamCreamer are you aware of how to load jQuery on WordPress?

Comment: @AlexF There are definitely errors. You need to learn some basic debugging with the developer tools in your browser. Press F12

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ - use it

Comment: @j08691 sorry about that. I looked up how to see the errors and am properly debugging it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".acord").accordion({
        header: "> h3",
        heightStyle: "content",
        collapsible: true,
    });
    jQuery(".acorda").accordion({
        header: "h3",
        heightStyle: "content",
        active: false,
        collapsible: true,
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I gave it a try, but I'm getting an error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: Jquery is not defined`.

Comment: Hey @AugustoMonteiro, thanks for the answer. I see how this should work, but I'm getting an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).accordion is not a function`.

Comment: Cool, this means that the accordion plugin isn't being loaded

Comment: you have to add [jQueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/) to be able to use the accordion, I looked at the source code of the page you added on the description and the ui isn't being loaded

Comment: thanks for the advice. I'm using a WordPress site so I'm not sure I can download the JQuery UI from the link you provided and then include it in my website. Is there a script tag I can include to load the accordion plugin?

Comment: yeah, you can add a CDN https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: but you have to add on the head tag, so you'll have to edit you theme

Comment: I added the code `<script src="code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` to the `header.php` of my theme in between the `<head>` tags, but I'm still getting the error that the accordion plugin isn't loading.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, do you added on the production one?, the same one that you provided the link on description?

Comment: Yeah I have. Everything is production now.

Comment: In the console log for the page I am getting an error saying `Unexpected token <` for the line I included in the header.php file `<script src="code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: let me know if it worked `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

`

Comment: I fixed the url and the error I'm getting now is `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).smartresize is not a function`. What I've researched on it points to having two javascript script tags present.

Comment: nice answer :D!

Answer (score 0):

You can inline your script in your theme's `functions.php`.

This assumes your scripts are `enqueue`-ed.

If the accordion jquery extension library is `enqueue`-d with a `$handle` of `accordion`, you can write it this way.

```
$accordion = <<<HERE
$(".acord").accordion({
    header: "> h3",
    heightStyle: "content",
    collapsible: true,
});
$(".acorda").accordion({
    header: "h3",
    heightStyle: "content",
    active: false,
    collapsible: true,
});
HERE;

wp_add_inline_script( 'accordion', $accordion );
```

Answer (score -1):

On your Website you are using $ in your script whereas on website jQuery is used try this code
`jQuery(".acord").accordion({
        header: "> h3",
        heightStyle: "content",
        collapsible: true,
    });
    jQuery(".acorda").accordion({
        header: "h3",
        heightStyle: "content",
        active: false,
        collapsible: true,
    });`

Comment: It wont work as well, because when he execute javascript, html element dont exists yet and jQuery object is empty. You'd need to add $( document ).ready()

Comment: Gave this a try as well. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes but this change needs to be done along with $(document).ready() thanks for the correction cheers.